# How can I find which view from which controller calling an action?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller, action

For example I have an "action-one" in "controller-one", if it called from views of that controller, return is different when it called from views of another controllers; So I should know which view from which controller calling an action.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to just have a flag, as an optional method parameter that you would use to specify and check in your controller.

But it is better to keep shared code in a different method if possible and have different actions for different purposes.

If what you needed was something that would not necessarily need a different action, then just pass the action name or any other identifier you wish to use and then check and do the different stuff you need to do based on their identifier.

Comment: Thank you @staa99, all of your suggestions are useful but I want check it from request route information.

Comment: Not yet,is it required? I thought if I can get view and controller name I can have different returns in one action.

Comment: The http request sent from the view would usually not contain information about which specific view is sending the request, but it would specify the route and might also pass additional data as part of the http request, if you explicitly pass the view details as part of the request, you can check the request data in the controller action the route maps to and make your decisions based on the data you get.

Comment: Please specify the framework you are using if you are using one